# Why does the brush in texture painting have hard cuts?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image]I wanted to paint a cartoon style bark on my tree model but while testing it the brush stroke had this hard edge cut instead of a soft fade edge. Also, parts of the model couldn't be painted in creating this jagged glitchy look not to mention the colors start to brighten when you paint over them which might be a problem if I want them separated.

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=4olVJNAA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/4olVJNAA/)

Comment: With the downloaded file I do not get these sharp edges between the lower and the upper part like seen in your screenshot. I only get sharp edges when I'm painting on the left and right border because the paint does not automatically wrap around to the invisible backside smoothly, but that's just how it works. Also painting with white in _Overlay_ mode gives quite weird results, if I paint more than once in a certain it soon becomes a yellow color. I don't know what kind of look you want to achieve, but I would choose a lighter brown and switch the paint mode to _Mix_ and reduce the _Strength_

Comment: So, the sharp edges are areas I can't see I'll just be careful then.  I was going for a world of warcraft look on the bark guess I should've added that.